# Include jsp file from another jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I deployed a small project on a server (on a shared hosting) and I have a problem there, it cannot see the included file.

So, I have the file:
`public_html/test/index.jsp`:

that has the code:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsps/aaa.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

and another file: `public_html/WEB-INF/jsps/aaa.jsp`

And if i access index.jsp like:
`www.mydomain.com/test/index.jsp`

I get the error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/WEB-INF/jsps/aaa.jsp&quot; not found
```

The problem is that I cannot include a file from a different directory!

In the localhost environment, where I developed the project I don't have this problem, but on the server I have it.

Do you know why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

just try the following code:

```
<jsp:include page="../WEB-INF/jsps/aaa.jsp"/>
```

instead of the one you wrote with end tag. `<jsp:xxx ..` should not have an end tag.. Generally I would suggest you avoid saving your `jsp` files inside WEB-INF since it's not a good practice (first time I see). and as I suggested earlier you can always mention the whole url as:

```
<jsp:include page="http://www.domain.com/public_html/WEB-INF/jsps/aaa.jsp"/>
```

I hope it works for you this time.

Comment: the first code don't work, and from my opinion is normal not to work, because is like include a file from the directory: /test/jsps/aaa.jsp but the file is not there!, is in WEB-INF/jsps/aaa.jsp

i get error even from the second code

Comment: Could you edit your question and show the path to both of the files? , I had to write example url since I don't know the path.

Comment: i don't understand what to check?

Comment: I have updated my answer , check it. I wrote it as comment so that you get a notification.